# release app not running after clicking back button and again going back to app

Tags: flutter

I have built flutter app which works fine with debug mode but in release mode when I install app for very first time it goes to login screen but when I press back button and go out from app and again try to open app it now do not go to login instead it shows white screen

I am using this for splash screen # flutter_native_splash:

## background_image: "assets/images/onboarding/splash.png"

## android_12:

## # Splash screen background color.

## color: "#D9A250"

## fullscreen: true

I search lot about this issue in internet but not found any solution

Comment: android 12 and later versions remove splash background image instead use color : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#:~:text=The%20window%20background%20consists%20of%20a%20single%20opaque%20color.%20If%20the%20window%20background%20is%20set%20and%20is%20a%20plain%20color%2C%20it%20is%20used%20by%20default%20if%20the%20attribute%20isn%27t%20set.